# Limit with complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Does these limits involving the principal branch of the natural logarithm exists?
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \ln(-i|z|-1)$$
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\ln(z^2-1)$$

I think the first limit is just $i\pi$. But I don't know how to justify it.

For the second limit, the point $z\rightarrow 0$ is in the branch cut. So I think that the limit there does not exist because $\ln$ is not defined. Is this correct?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The principal value of $\ln w$ is defined for $w < 0$, but the limit is not taken along the real axis ($\lim_{z \to 0, z \in \mathbb R} \ln(z^2 - 1)$ exists). $\ln |w|$ tends to zero, we need to consider the limit of $\arg w$. $w = -i |z| - 1$ approaches $-1$ from below in the complex plane. For $w = z^2 - 1$, consider $z = e^{-\pi i/4} \epsilon$ and $z = e^{\pi i/4} \epsilon$ (or $z = \epsilon$) with $\epsilon \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: I consider $\mathfrak{I}(z^2-1)=2xy$. This can be positive or negative. If approaching from below the limit is $-\pi i$ and from above the limit is $\pi i$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z \in \mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, you have $\Im(-i \vert z \vert -1) = -\vert z \vert <0$.

Hence $$\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \ln(-i\vert z \vert -1)=-i\pi.$$

*Note: however the map $f : z \mapsto \ln(-i\vert z \vert -1)$ is not continuous at zero as $f(0) =i\pi$.*

And you’re right regarding the second limit: it doesn’t exist.

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.ne , thanks for your answer. Can you explain a little bit more on why is the first limit $-i\pi$?

Comment: As $-i \vert z \vert -1$ converges to $-1$, the requested limit is either $i\pi$ or $-i \pi$. It is in fact $-i \pi$ because the imaginary part of $f(z)$ is negative for all $z \neq 0$.

Comment: Oh ok. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the fisrt one!
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \ln(-i|z|-1)$$
we know that $$e^{i{\theta}}=cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$$
$$ln(e^{i{\theta}})=ln(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)) $$
$$i\theta=ln(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))$$
$$\boxed{\theta=-iln(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))} \quad (1)$$
So, if we have: $$ln(-1)$$ it means that $$cos(\theta)=-1 \space and \space sin(\theta)=0$$
$$\theta=arccos(-1)$$
thus $$\theta={\pi}$$
Now we can substitute in $$ \quad (1)$$
$$\boxed{\pi=-iln(cos(\pi)+isin(\pi))}$$
$$\boxed{i{\pi=ln(-1)}}$$
You can justify the second exercise using the same way. (Sorry for my english and my typing skills)